# Is irrational roots occuring in conjugate pairs valid only for Binomial surds

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, irreducible-polynomials

Its well know that if a polynomial has Rational coefficients then irrational roots occur in conjugate pairs.

Will it be true for trinomial surds like for example if a polynomial has a root 
$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+1$ Then we get a polynomial as

$$x=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+1$$

$$x-1=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$$ Squaring both sides

$$x^2-2x+1=5+2\sqrt{6}$$

$$x^2-2x-4=2\sqrt{6}$$ again squaring we get

$$x^4-4x^3-4x^2+16x-8=0$$ will the other root be its rationalizing factor

Comment: In your "well known" quoted statement, what does "conjugate pairs" mean? That is, for a general polynomial with rational coefficients, what does it mean for two roots are "conjugate"?

Comment: i mean if a polynomial with rational coefficients has $3+\sqrt{5}$ has a root then other root is $3-\sqrt{5}$

Comment: Yes for that case, conjugate is opposite sign between. But what about a cubic, if it has a zero at $c$ then what does the conjugate of $c$ mean?

Comment: yes then also true for example the cubic $x^3-7x^2+10x-4=0$ has roots $1$ and two irrationals which are conjugates

Comment: I guess I'm wondering how one would *define* the term "conjugate" in a general case. Suppose e.g. $p(x)$ is some polynomial of degree $6$ with a rational root $r$ we could factor $p(x)=(x-r)q(x),$ then $q$ has degree $5$ and the definition of conjugate for zeros of $q$ is not immediately clear.

Comment: i am not getting your point for example if a polynomial with rational coefficients has a root of form $a+\sqrt{b}$ where $a$ and $b \gt 0$ are rational such that $\sqrt{b}$ is irrational, then the other root is its Conjugate $a-\sqrt{b}$. This rule is applicable for roots which are of the form $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ in which we can get polynomial with rational coefficients as $x^4-10x^2+1=0$ for which all the roots are $\pm \sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{3}$

Comment: More over in my above comment the least degree polynomial having rational coefficients with $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$ as one of its roots is of degree $4$, so we cannot obtain a cubic here if we intend to have rational coefficients

Comment: What I mean in my last comment is about what if the polynomial, for example of degree $5$ or more, does not happen to even have any zeroes of form $a+\sqrt{b}$ where $a,b$ rational and $b$ not a square of a rational. I think if it does have a zero of this type, then what you say is OK, namely the  conjugate will also be a zero of it. In my opinion your question would be improved if you defined what conjugate means, for example using radicals and a sign change, in the question itself rather than in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one finds the least degree integer polynomial having $c=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}$ as one of its roots [when set to $0$], then that polynomial $p(x)$ turns out to have degree $4.$ Since it has only degree $4$ one would expect that not all eight possible variations on $c$ obtained by changing $0$ or more signs on the three radicals will also be roots of $p(x)=0,$ and indeed one can check that the four roots are $c$ itself (no surprise there) along with the three other roots obtained from $c$ by changing *exactly* two signs before the three radicals.

So in general, if one defines a conjugate of a surd as anything obtained by changing one or more signs before the radicals, the results may or may not be zeros of the starting polynomial generated from the initial surd.

I also looked at the case of $c'=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ in the same way; this time the least degree polynomial $q(x)$ for $c'$ turns out to have degree $8,$ and a check reveals that here all eight "conjugates" obtained from $c'$ by changing zero or more signs are roots of $q(x)=0.$

Though I'm not really up on the topic, I think the relevant thing to look at for this question is Galois Theory.

Comment: Please tell how to find solution in Galois theory. I mean which terms, etc. to look after in that so as to explain your answer fully.