# Issues in Proof of conjugate irrational roots.

Tags: galois-theory, irrational-numbers

In the book titled Essays on Numbers and Figures, by Prasolov; it is [shown](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KNPr2Tmgu3IC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by a simple proof that conjugate root have different form than the original root of the form $m+n\sqrt{3}$.

I feel that the treatment is too primitive, as conjugate is shown of the form $m-n\sqrt{3}$ only.

If the underlying assumption for being a conjugate is that its product with the root gives a rational value; then $-m+n\sqrt{3}$ is also conjugate to $m+n\sqrt{3}$.

Second, the proof that uses equality of $m+n\sqrt{3}$ to $m_1+n_1\sqrt{3}$ is not clear as it is given that $m\ne m_1, n\ne n_1$, & still equality is used for proof.

I feel there should be a better approach shown, that confirms a single negation of signs in the conjugate; as well as to show that $m=m_1, n=n_1$.

[image]

In particular, it seems that the answer is given in Galois theory (as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2236337/424260)); but do not know what specific terms the author of the answer is referring to.

As the author is not active on mse for a long time, so request elaboration of the answer.

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "conjugate root have different form than the original root of the form $m+n\sqrt 3$" mean?  Please state all your assumptions and the desired conclusion clearly.

Comment: The proof you are referring to in your second point is absolutely valid. It is a proof by contradiction. Also, a desired property of "conjugation" is that it acts as identity on the rational numbers. However, the formula you suggest acts as minus identity.

Comment: It is also clearly not true that the definition of conjugate is that the product with the original should be rational.  Clearly there are infinitely many numbers with that property (if $\alpha$ is one such then $\lambda \times \alpha$ is another for every rational $\lambda$).

Comment: @lulu I am just quoting the author that states : "To that end let us first note that no number can be represented in two different ways in the form ..."

Comment: The sentence you write does not appear in the passage you quote.

Comment: @lulu If you wish the whole para. can be stated too, it is the first sentence in a para, there. Please explain by an example that if there is a given irrational  root, then there can be infinite numbers with the property that their product with the irrational root leads to a rational; without their being a conjugate to the root.

Comment: I don't understand.  I gave a complete proof in my example.  For $\sqrt 2$, say, any rational multiple of $\sqrt 2$ will work.  What's the problem?  And you keep saying "root" but you have defined no polynomial.  As I said originally, please state all your assumptions clearly.

Comment: I think, but am not at all sure, that you are just asking why there can't be two distinct pairs of rationals, $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ with $a+b\sqrt 3=c+d\sqrt 3$.  The answer to that, as the author correctly remarks, is that this would imply that $\sqrt 3\in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @lulu I would prefer abstract approach as an example would not serve my goal to searching in terms of Galois theory, This conclusion is reached by reading many posts here on similar topics. Still, can take $2+\sqrt{3}$ as a root; but you have gone better & have taken $\sqrt{2}$; by taking only the irrational part, So, it itself can be its conjugate as their product leads to a rational; hence my point fails. So, I add the assumption of having irrational root of the form $m+n\sqrt{c}, m,n,c\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Anyway, in the context of algebraic numbers two numbers are conjugates (*by a definition*), if and only if they share the same minimal polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$. The minimal polynomial of $m+n\sqrt3$, $n\in\Bbb{Q}^*, m\in\Bbb{Q}$, is $f(x)=(x-m)^2-3n^2$. And the zeros of that polynomial are $m\pm n\sqrt3$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot for the needed defn. Request to provide definition's linkage to the comment posted by Pedro Tamaroff
 (at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/555154/424260), which states: "The map $a+b\sqrt{D} \rightarrow a−b\sqrt{D}$ has the property that it preserves sums and products,...". Request to provide some details of this too. If possible, please make an answer, as the topic has not attracted here (on mse, to any related question so far) any of the details that such answer would provide.

Comment: This is to elucidate my last comment that serves to integrate a comment to another related topic post. Although, such linking has made the last comment complex, but wanted to integrate with the comment of @JyrkiLahtonen. Basically, want to ask two things: (i) How to show that the map between conjugates preserves the two properties of sum & product; as in the comment by 'Pedro Tamaroff' (at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/555154/424260), (ii) is there a way to link the concept of 'minimal polynomial' with the preservation of properties as in (i) between conjugates.